# How do mentors affect co-op play in DCUO?

Tags: dc-universe-online

Can I help a friend with missions if they have a different mentor? After unlocking the Watchtower and the ability to travel between cities, I assume I can visit my friend who is allied with  Superman, while I am allied with Batman. **Can I help my friend with missions in his city, and vice versa?**

*And by "help" I mean accept the mission, see the objectives, get the rewards, etc. Not just run around blindly attacking people while he chases objective markers and gets all the goodies.*

Other than being in the same city from the start, is there any pro/con to having the same mentor as a friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is incorrect.  Some missions are shareable.  While grouped, if your friend opens their Journal, and selects the mission, one of the options at the bottom is Share.

Even if it is not a shareable mission, your friend will get credit for any tasks performed while the two of you are grouped ... even if it's annoying to not be able to see what they are.  Even while not grouped, there is an algorithm to give credit to people nearby, if the system deems that they somehow participated.

To enter mentor-specific instances: while grouped, the person with the mentor goes in the teleporter first, while the other person stands outside.  A moment later, the teleporter will appear for that person, though it was previously not visible.

Some instances are still not available to groups.  One I recall in particular is Nest Egg ... the Penguin solo mission near Gotham University.  I believe you can only enter it as an individual because it's a shared teleporter for both the levelling mission what used to be a walk-in for the solo Challenges.

Answer (score 1):

So you will be able to do some missions, mainly side missions and such. You wont be able to do any mentor specific missions but you will be able to join the instance with them and help out. As for the second question not really because once you two hit 30 and you start end game mentor wont matter, heck for some end game missions factions doesn't even matter(different subject just look up suicide squad/task force x in regards to dcuo). But ya hoped this has helped.